# How do I test my classifier accuracy against random values?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification

I've set up my first scikit-learn example to play with and I'm trying to gauge accuracy on my predictions. I've got training and test lists set up fine, but I'm getting ~0.95 accuracy even if I give it random values.

This looks to be because I'm checking for 0/1 labels, and 95% of the labels are zero's, so it's guessing on 0's and getting 0.95 accuracy (I think?). Obviously this isn't what I want.

How do I go about deciding if my classifiers are working, and how do I get meaningful accuracy values?

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should flag it to be moved to Cross Validated (if it hasn't been answered there yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a clear class imbalance issue. Your classifier is predicting `0` all the time knowing it will be right 95% of the time. You can inspect this by calling `predict(X_test)` on your fitted classifier. If all the values are `0` you know this is the case.

To get a better idea on how the model performs you can upsample the data labelled with `1` or down sample the data labelled with `0`. You can use this [package](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/imbalanced-learn) which builds off scikit-learn and implements a number of resampling methods. Alternatively, you can use scikit learns [resampling](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.resample.html) method. Which will bootstrap new data points for you.

Comment: Thanks. Should all test data have a 50/50 split or 0/1 then ideally? Is that a standard data preparation task?

Comment: Ideally you want the test proportion of labels to match you training proportion. This can be achieve through [stratified folds](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html).